# Excel - get date based on sequential number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 4 columns in my excel workbook. Column A is Employee ID, column B is Effective Date, column C is Sequence number and column D is End Date.

What I'm trying to do is I need to do matching for Column A,B and C, if both 3 column have duplicated data then the End Date will be filled in 31/12/2018 for the last sequential number and the End Date before the last sequential number will the same as Effective Date.

Example:

```
1001  12/03/2018   1    12/03/2018
1001  12/03/2018   2    12/03/2018
1001  12/03/2018   3    12/03/2018
1001  12/03/2018   4    31/12/2018
1001  13/03/2018   1    13/03/2018
1001  13/03/2018   2    31/12/2018
1001  14/03/2018   1    31/12/2018
1002  12/03/2018   1    12/03/2018
1002  12/03/2018   2    31/12/2018
1002  13/03/2018   1    31/12/2018
```

Edit:

[worksheet result screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amF5G.png)

[Condition error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfrQk.png)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that your values start from row 2 (because first row has headers). Change the format in column D to **"dd/mm/yyyy"**. Then type the below formula in column **D**:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,$A2)=$C2,DATEVALUE("31/12/2018"),$B2)
```

Then drag this down to your last row. This should give you what you need

Comment: Thank you very much. It definitely helped. But the date format in the DATEVALUE i guess need to be in "mm/dd/yyyy" format, else it will return the value like "#VALUE!"

Comment: After I type the formula in my actual worksheet, the formula didn't work. Actually there are even more records for ID 1001. I will amend the question.